# How can I recognize a face using landmarks points?

Tags: opencv, face-detection, face-recognition, dlib

I am working with face recognition using Eigenface algorithm. But I need to recognize a face using distances of parts of the face or something like calculating values. But now I have some points of facial landmarks. And how they can be used to recognize a face?

[image]

Comment: I don't think it is a better approach as compared to Eigenface.

Answer (score 0):

When face pose to different directions, or do kinds of facial emotion, the landmarks are different. So landmarks is not good for face recognition. In my knowledge, the face landmarks mainly for emotion analysis, pose estimation, not for recognition.

---

Here is a (open?) handbook(2011) of face recognition searched by Google.

https://cours.etsmtl.ca/sys828/REFS/Intro/Hanbook%20of%20Face%20Recognition.pdf

A table of face recognition comparison:

[image]

In OpenCV, mainly face recognition algorithms available now are:

```
Eigenfaces (see EigenFaceRecognizer::create)
Fisherfaces (see FisherFaceRecognizer::create)
Local Binary Patterns Histograms (see LBPHFaceRecognizer::create)
```

See this link : https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/da/d60/tutorial_face_main.html